# How does one serve multiple static pages from a single S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Let's assume one has an Amazon S3 bucket `example.com` configured for static hosting. In the configuration, the console allows setting an index file and an optional error file. But I'm struggling to figure out how to add another page to the site. I thought this would be straight forward but I cannot find the answer in the official documentation or on the internet.

If I want to add one more page to the static site (e.g. `example.com/page2`) and there is a `page2.html` file already in the S3 bucket at the root, where is the correct place to make this routing configuration? Can it be done through the S3 console? Or does it need to be configured through some kind of a DNS record? As a further complication, this needs to also work with and without the www in the URL.

On the DNS side I currently have the following configuration:

```
CNAME | WWW | www.example.com.s3-website-east-1.amazonaws.com | TTL 30 min
URL Redirect Record | @ | http://www.example.com unmasked
```

Comment: If the existing `page2.html` file is not working for you, please tell us what error messages you see when trying to access it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you trying to access the page at example.com/page2.html or example.com/page2

If you want to access the page at example.com/page2 then create a 'folder' called page2 off the root and in that folder put a file called index.html

If you want to use example.com/page2.html, then create a file called page2.html and put it in the 'root' of the bucket.

Answer (score 1):

Simply create a file called `page2.html`. It will be accessible via `example.com/page2.html`.

No routing configuration is required.

The index file alias is only used if no page is specified (eg they go to `example.com/`).

As for mapping `www.example.com` to `example.com`, you would create another bucket with the name `www.example.com` and use "Redirect requests" to point back to `example.com`. (If using a `CNAME` works for you, that's probably easier, but test it first to see if it functions as expected. See: [Mapping naked domain (www.domain.com) to static website which is saved in S3](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/13041))

See: [Configuring a static website using a custom domain registered with Route 53](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html) (Follow the manual steps rather than automating via CloudFormation, so you can better understand what has been configured)

Comment: I just realized while reading your answer that my bucked is named "example" instead of "example.com". I'm going to correct that to see if it solves the issue.

Comment: Ok I've corrected the bucket naming issue and now have two correctly named buckets with the www.example.com bucket redirecting to example.com. I have a CNAME record mapping to the example.com resource. But the problem still persists. I can navigate to the index page but not page2. The error message for example.com/page2 is the default message in firefox "Hmm. We’re having trouble finding that site." that appears when a site does not exist.  Please note I am using Namecheap rather than Route 53.

Comment: Oh, you cannot use Namecheap for the name resolution. Instead, you must use a Static Website and an Amazon Route 53 alias. See: [Configuring a static website using a custom domain registered with Route 53](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html) Fortunately, you can use Namecheap to delegate the name resolution to Route 53 without moving the whole domain registration. See: [Making Amazon Route 53 the DNS service for an existing domain - Amazon Route 53](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/MigratingDNS.html)